# Elements wont play when combine javascript in wordpress with wp-rocket

Tags: javascript, wordpress, concatenation

hello this is my website https://www.e-domus.gr. I want to use Wp-rocket to cache my files. So in order to  make my site really fast i need to combine js files into one. Problem is that even though there are almost non error, Menu on mobile is not displaying and sliders wont play etc you can see it here https://www.e-domus.gr/nea-archiki/ This page for example has a rev slider but it doesn't play at all. I really need some help cause i cant find see the problem. than you
Things already did.
I followed this withou wp-rocket js options
https://www.lbfl.co.uk/combine-javascript-files-wordpress/

Also excluded

/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js

/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/revolution.tools.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/rs6.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/vendors/woocommerce-add-to-cart.js

/edomuscms/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist-premium/assets/js/jquery.selectBox.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist-premium/assets/js/jquery.yith-wcwl.js

/edomuscms/plugins/yith-woocommerce-brands-add-on-premium/assets/js/swiper.jquery.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/select2/select2.full.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/yith-woocommerce-brands-add-on-premium/assets/js/yith-wcbr.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js

/edomuscms/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/js-cookie/js.cookie.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/woocommerce.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart-fragments.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/yith-woocommerce-order-tracking-premium/assets/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js

/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.form.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/yith-woocommerce-order-tracking-premium/assets/js/ywot.js

/edomuscms/plugins/wp-gdpr-compliance/assets/js/front.js

/edomuscms/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/js_composer_front.min.js

/wp-includes/js/imagesloaded.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/bower/isotope/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js

/edomuscms/themes/woodmart/js/theme.min.js

/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js

/wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js

/edomuscms/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js

/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I would look through their documentation.

https://docs.wp-rocket.me/category/1231-file-optimization

A few things with caching/deferred loading etc.

Just because you can combine JS/CSS doesn't mean you should. It warns you that you may need to undo it based on your theme as it can be a BREAKING change.

Composer seems to have a lot of issues with it.

You will have to toy with the settings to see which combo works with your theme/plugins. Sometimes plugins aren't setup for their files to be moved.

Example - trying to instantiate a JS mobile menu before the JS is available.

If you deferred loading and it tries to call that prior to it being available.

That said. WP Rocket isn't going to fix a lot of those issues.

You do not have control over external resources.

[image]

I would look at those 23 external files to see if they can be served locally. Thats a lot of external JS.